# CANBUS Baudrates Configuration Meaning

Tags: stm32, can-bus

What is the logic of a canbus baudrate configuration as follows, where the numbers are determined ?

```
  CAN_InitStructure.CAN_BS1 = CAN_BS1_2tq;
    CAN_InitStructure.CAN_BS2 = CAN_BS2_3tq;
    CAN_InitStructure.CAN_Prescaler = 16;
    CAN_Init(CAN1, &CAN_InitStructure);
```

Comment: Your title is too vague and your question miss too much information, please see [ask] and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot about

```
CAN_InitStructure.SyncJumpWidth = CAN_SJW_1TQ;
```

The bitrate will be:

```
 BITRATE = (CANCLOCK / CAN_InitStructure.CAN_Prescaler) / (1 + CAN_InitStructure.CAN_BS1 + CAN_InitStructure.CAN_BS2)
```

Where CANCLOCK is the CAN peripheral clock in Hz. It depends on your clock tree configuration.

Your time quanta frequency is `TQF = CANCLOCK / CAN_InitStructure.CAN_Prescaler`

Time quanta itself `TQ = 1/TQF` (in seconds)

The bit time is `BITTIME = TQ * (CAN_InitStructure.SyncJumpWidth + CAN_InitStructure.CAN_BS1 + CAN_InitStructure.CAN_BS2)`

Remember that xxxx_3tq means **3** TQs

Comment: @CKocar the all values are in TQ not in the real values behind those definitions. But I think it is quite obvious

Comment: SJW has usually nothing to do with baudrate initialization. It should rather be sync _segment_ + whatever they call the other segments on the specific controller (normally called phase seg 1 and 2). The sync segment is where edges are supposed to occur and is typically hardcoded to 1 in hardware. Whereas SJW is the allowance for how much the clock may deviate - you set it to larger values 2 or 3 when you use the highest baudrates.

Comment: Lib/driver writers are frequently confused over this; Atmel did just like you do here in their driver and app notes... I had a long support discussion with them until they finally admitted it was wrong. The point being: when you need to adjust SJW because you use 800kbps/1000kbps, you'll screw up the baudrate formula. So where did you get this formula from? Would be amusing if ST has the same bug as Atmel.

Comment: @Lundin Actually you are right. Because I usually do not change SJW and it is by default 1 same as synchronization and eventually I was using it as the synonymous which wrong of course. Changed the answer accordingly

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit of a pain to configure baudrate for CAN, but all CAN controllers work quite similar.

You wish to have the sample point per bit as near the ideal location of 87.5% (as per CAN in Automation/CANopen recommendations). To get it there, you need to tell how many TQ (time quanta) there are before the sample point, and after it.

The length of each TQ is determined by the CAN controller's clock, derived and divided from the system clock, the length of each TQ being 1 clock cycle. 16 TQ is usually ideal, so you'll want to pick a divisor after that. If you run system clock at 16MHz, you can pick a divisor by 16 to get 1MHz CAN clock. Keep in mind that internal RC oscillator is a no-go for CAN! You must use external crystal or oscillator for sufficient accuracy.

The segments before the sample point are usually called sync segment (fixed 1 TQ), propagation segment and phase segment 1 - terminology is a bit different from controller to controller. These segments together should make up 87.5% of the desired baudrate, and the segment after the sample point, usually called phase segment 2, should make up the rest.

Syncronization jump width (SJW) has nothing to do with the baudrate calculation itself, but it is related. SJW determines how many TQ the clock is allowed to deviate for the given baudrate - for 800kbps or 1000kbps you'd set it to 3, otherwise 1 should work.